# elementary OS Freya 0.3.2 won't boot after installing tlp

Tags: boot

I just spent 2 hours installing all my programs and getting everything set up the way I wanted it. The last thing I did was install tlp... I used the command `sudo tlp start` and my system suddenly froze up, I couldn't move the mouse or anything. So I shut it off by holding down the power button, restarted, and now it just freezes while it's booting. Is there any way I can uninstall tlp from my system without actually starting up the os? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you modify tlp's configuration file by chance?

Answer (score 1):

To remove software before the system boots you need to use recovery mode which can be accessed by holding down <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> while booting and selecting recovery mode. Then open the shell or terminal (something like that) and type `sudo apt-get remove <package you installed tlp with>` and also type `sudo apt-get autoremove` after that. Reboot your system and it should boot